# A rule for when variables get assigned to one another

Tags: javascript

Can I confirm that the reason code snippet 2 (&3) work is because something like: when `variableA` is fully, or partly, assigned to `variableB`, `variableB` always gets what `variableA` is at the time `variableB` is (last) initialised?

---

*The aim: to make a function that continually prints `"red0"`, `"red1"` `"red2"` etc.*

In the first snippet, when we come to log out `colorNum`, `colorNum` doesn't dynamically update its `num` value. It's as if `colorNum` captures what `num` at the last moment `colorNum` was initialised.

```js
num = 0;
colorNum = "red" + num;

function printObject() {
  console.log(colorNum);
  num++;
}

setInterval(printObject, 2000);
```

Here `colorNum` is continually reinitialised. So the updated value of `num` is captured in `colorNum` because `colorNum` is reinitialised after `num` is updated.

```js
let num = 0;
let colorNum = "red" + num;

function printObject() {
  colorNum = "red" + num;
  console.log(colorNum);
  num++;
}

setInterval(printObject, 2000);
```

Similarly the *return* expression of `fun` is a new expression every-time `fun` is called. The `return` expression captures the value of `num` at the point in time the `return` expression is created.

```js
num = 0;

fun = function(){
return "red" + num;
}

function printObject() {
  console.log(fun());
  num++;
}

setInterval(printObject, 2000);
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In languages like JavaScript (which is to say, most common programming languages), assigning a primitive value from one variable to another establishes absolutely no permanent relationship between them. The assignment operator is an immediate imperative, after which the two variables sail off into the night.

Also, note that the assignment

```
colorNum = "red" + num;
```

is evaluated by first computing the value of the right-hand side. The string constant "red" and the value of `num` are concatenated. After that has happened, *before* that result value is assigned, there is no remaining trace of `num`.  All the runtime has is the result value from the concatenation, and that value has nothing whatsoever to do with the variable `num`.

Now, *reference* assignment is a different story, to some extent, or at least superficially, but as far as the language actually works it's the same story. So in

```
let x = { a: "hello" };
let y = x;
y.a = "goodbye";
console.log(x.a);
```

the value of property "a" in the only object involved will change. However, if subsequently:

```
let x = { a: "zebra" };
y.a = "giraffe";
console.log(x.a);
```

it'll still be "zebra" because assigning a new object reference to `x` has absolutely no effect on `y`.

From older languages like C, from which JavaScript syntax is at least loosely derived, an assignment expression is literally a request to copy a value stored in memory from one place to another. It *looks* like algebra but it does not work like pencil-and-paper algebra. JavaScript is *conceptually* a higher level language, but the semantics are still the same.

Comment: These examples really help. The little rule I have with reference data-types (which I think are just objects) is 'if `objA` is assigned to `objB`, `objB` points to the *same* object that `objA` was initialised with. However, later on, if `objA` is reinitialised (having its properties changed is *not* reinitialising it) then `objB` keeps the 'old' object. What do you think of that?

Comment: @tonitone120 that is correct. An object reference is itself really just a simple value; it's basically like a memory address, conceptually (who knows what it really is inside any particular JavaScript runtime, but it doesn't matter). Two different object references refer to two different objects, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You're right in your assumption. In code snippet 2 and 3 `num` gets added every time. In 1 it is only added 1 time. At the moment of assignment the variable's value is taken. Whether it changes later doesn't matter.

Note that if you study Javascript a bit longer, you'll notice a different behaviour for `Object` and other types where assignment doesn't mean later changes to the original are disregarded, but this is a more advanced topic.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like partial assignment; either you assign or don't assign.

In the first example, where you write `colorNum = "red" + num;`, you are not partially assigning `num` to `colorNum`. Rather you are using num in creating a new string, and then you are assigning that new string to the `colorNum` variable. So, as long as you don't update the colorNum with new value, it continues to hold the old value (As long as we are dealing with primitive values like numbers, strings, boolean, etc. This changes when we are dealing with objects which are usually passed around as references).

In example 2 & 3, you are updating the value of `colorNum` variable every time and hence they are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

In your code examples there is no "magic" behind the variables assignment. The only difference is the order of commands.

Normally, all commands run synchronously, so one-by-one (we are not looking into parallel now). Of course, there are some differences between programming languages, for example in JavaScript all variable and function definitions (`var`) goes to the start of the code.

Let's return to your code.

Your first example:

```js
num = 0;
colorNum = "red" + num;

function printObject() {
  console.log(colorNum);
  num++;
}

setInterval(printObject, 2000);
```

Actually it has `var` before variable creation. Also I will add line numbers, so it will be easier to understand the order of commands:

```js
/* 1 */ var num = 0;
/* 2 */ var colorNum = "red" + num;
/* 3 */ 
/* 4 */ function printObject() {
/* 5 */   console.log(colorNum);
/* 6 */   num++;
/* 7 */ }
/* 8 */ 
/* 9 */ setInterval(printObject, 2000); // 9
```

- First of all, functions and variables created, so first commands will be in line `1`, `2`, `4` (we create function, but do not run it, just create).
- After command in line `1` we will have `num` equal to `0`.
- After command in line `2` we will have `colorNum` equal to `"red" + num` that is `"red" + 0` that is `"red0"`
- Now we come to line `9`. Here we calling function `printObject` every 2 seconds, so...
- ...when 2 seconds passed we call function `printObject`, so:

  - we run command in line `5` and print to console our `colorNum` that is still equal to "red0"`
  - line `6` increase `num` by 1, so now we have `num` equal to `1`
- ... another 2 seconds passed and we call function again, so:

  - we run command in line `5` and print to console our `colorNum` that is still equal to "red0"`(because we did not change the value inside`colorNum`after it was set in line`2`)
  - line `6` increase `num` by 1, so now we have `num` equal to `2`
- and so on... We print always the same `colorNum` as it was created on line `2` and we never change it again, so `console.log` will use its original value

Ok, now I will be quicker. Your second example has one additional line inside the function: `colorNum = "red" + num;`. That is very good, because now we change the value of `colorNum` before we print it to console.

Your third example has different idea of getting the value that we will print to console. You have added another function, that calculates the value. So your code:

```js
num = 0;

fun = function(){
return "red" + num;
}

function printObject() {
  console.log(fun());
  num++;
}

setInterval(printObject, 2000);
```

Is equal to:

```js
num = 0;

function printObject() {
  console.log("red" + num);
  num++;
}

setInterval(printObject, 2000);
```

This is because your function `fun` has only one line of code: `"red" + num`, so I can replace this function call with this line.

Actually, you even do not need to have a separate line for `num++`, or even the `printObject` can be "inlined":

```js
var num = 0;

setInterval(() => console.log("red" + num++), 2000);
```

Comment: clever refactoring at the end! Forgot I could actually just flesh out the function when I place it as an argument in `setInterval`.